# A situation regarding AVR and bad power grid voltage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, generator, damage

I have a question regarding the following situation:

Some poultry farm has taken some serious losses when their diesel generator died, only being able to provide backup for 45 minutes and killing several ten of thousand of chickens. The reason they had to switch to the generator was because the power grid voltage was oscilating wildly (even managing to activate the generator transfer switch several times previously). A technical lab has pinpointed the AVR card as the root of the malfunction. Here comes the trouble:
After an technical examination, the damage was traced to a malfunction of the AVR card of said generator. Here comes my trouble:

-Insurer A has refused payment because the damage was "caused by the electro-mechanical effort of the repeated activation and deactivation via transfer switch, forced by the oscilating voltage in the power grid". Thus the fault falls solely on the power grid operator.

-Insurer B is questioning this refusal as "the AVR card only regulates the output voltage of the generator, having no connection to the power grid. The damage caused is more probably due to insufficient maintenance or card age, as the repeated deactivation and activation would not be enough to put such stress on the card." Insurer B wants to cover the payment but demands the farm to install power line monitors and additional surge protection devices, perform maintance with more frequency .

-After the incident, the Insured has purchased a replacement AVR and 1 additional diesel generator.

**Questions:**

-Who is right: Insured A or B?
-Taking into account the poor performance of the power grid voltage, would the measures taken by the insured be enough to prevent or lower the chance of a repeat of thie incident? Is insurer B's advice regarding this matter sound? Would you suggest any other measures?

Thank you very much for your advice, as this area is not one of our expertise.

Comment: A totally off-grid backup generator system that could be cut in manually would be prudent with perhaps some sort of alarm system if the farmer is remote. That and better insurance. This is not really a pertinent question for here though. Voting to close.

Comment: @Trevor Sorry if it's off-topic for this community, but I don't know anywhere else to ask.

Comment: Maybe the legal department... and there is an electrical component to the question..  so not sure either.

Comment: @Trevor Don't worry for the legal part. The important part is the electrical: Is there a significant chance that a supply fluctuation could damage a regulator card?

Comment: That's the problem though, Either reason is plausible. Moreover, if the system was badly maintained, the chances of failure due to line variations increases. Unfortunately there is no way to tell which was the prime cause. However, the insurer also has some responsibility to inspected and approve the installation before covering the farmer. At this point it really is a legal issue. But as I said, a backup backup system would be prudent. Not just for cost, but replacing livestock is not a trivial matter. That and making sure the insurer will cover it properly.

Comment: @MPadilla we don't offer legal advice or professional advice on this level, you'll need to hire a licensed engineer to review the installation. This also has nothing to do with electrical design, which is what this forum is all about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two faults here, the power grid fluctuations and the generator failing.

A transfer switch is heavily interlocked to prevent the generator and grid being connected to the load at the same time (That is very much the point of the things), so the generator AVR should have no visibility of the grid because it is just not connected to it. 
The generator automatic start logic can of course see the grid, but from the description it is the AVR that failed (Not the same thing).

A faulty AVR card might trip the generator off line, which actually would be very much working as designed in terms of failing safe, and faulty AVR is a perfectly reasonable root cause for the generator failure (And may or may not be related to age, maintenance, or anything else), but that is a separate question from what was going on with the grid.

So as I say, two faults, the grid and the generator, but they are not necessarily related.

Now standby power plants failing when needed is a common trick, and is why critical installations will test for a few hours a month (sometimes into a load bank), to catch problems and such things as blocked fuel filters and contaminated fuel. I would suggest such as being good practise with any diesel set, and in fact there is no reason not to actually run the facility off generator for a few hours a month to confirm correct operation (Actually shut down the grid feed and confirm generator startup, then leave it to run for a few hours).

You want the tests to be long enough to get the engines and alternators fully up to temperature and at a heavy enough load to show up any restrictions in the fuel supply.

Further, some simple alarm telemetry to send a text message to the farmer in the event of grid failure or generator failure (Also in the event of air temperature in the facility moving outside safe limits (Which is probably what killed the birds)) would be a worthwhile investment, knowing that the fans have stopped for ANY reason seems worthwhile.

Regards, Dan.

Comment: Thanks to you and @Charles Cowie for your helpful answers. They will help to prevent repeating this event in the future. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that both are wrong. The system that controls the transfer should be designed to prevent repeated activation and de-activation of the transfer switch. Once a transfer from the grid to the DG is initiated the load should remain connected to the DG for long enough after grid power is restored to assure that grid power is stable.

There is also the possibility that the AVR card is not sufficiently robust. I doubt that the card failed due to insufficient maintenance or card age. I would investigate the card age and the maintenance recommendations of the manufacturer.

Comment: +1 for the lockout feature. Even if the thing did fail because of supply fluctuations, the insurer should have paid out and gone after the supply company. Seems like just another case of insurance companies finding any reason not to pay out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Mr. @Charles Is there an example of device in the market that could provide the alarm and lockout function? Or is it something that already comes with the transfer switch? They used a Stamford SX460 AVR card, by the way.

Comment: @Trevor Insurer B wants to pay but Insurer A has the last word. They used a Stamford SX460 AVR card for a 136 kVA generator, by the way.

Comment: The transfer switch must come with some control system that determines when to activate the switch. If the switch can transfer back to grid power automatically, some delay must be built into that function. Some things to investigate are how that system is designed to operate, if it operated as designed, if the design was adequate, if something better was offered when it was purchased, if the same supplier supplied both the DG and transfer switch.